# Does 'Model' reads all the rows from the table when initialized? (performance)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a model named 'AccountModel' and it has `public virtual DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }` property by default. I'm using it with `Linq`. I just wonder, is that mean model reads all rows from the table?

For example, I just want to perform a (basic) login operation and first I need to know existance of username and password pair. I can do it with a simple sql query (`SELECT Id, Password FROM Accounts WHERE Username = 'test'`) or I'll do it with `Linq` (`model.Account.First(x => x.Username == 'test')`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you go read up  about entity framework and deferred execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just wonder, is that mean model reads all rows from the table?

No, it simply creates a map from your property Account to the table that stores `Account` objects.  You would not actually read data until you do something that consumes data.

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var result = ctx.Account.Where(a => a.Category == "Prime");
```

will not even read any data.  It is not until you actually do something with `result`

```
    int primeAccounts = result.Count();
```

that any data is actually read.

> For example, I just want to perform a (basic) login operation and first I need to know existance of username and password pair

You can do something like

```
bool valid = ctx.Account
                .Where(a => a.Username == 'test' && 
                       a.Password = 'HopefullyAHashAndNotAnActualPlaintextPassword')
                .Any();
```

Comment: Namely (almost) my two implementations are the same for sql-server, right?

Comment: Yes the two accomplish the same thing.